# How to use a type of a class as argument to a template

Tags: c++, templates

I apologize for the vague title, but I want to create a template class that is defined for some pointer to a pointer to a function. Currently, I have this:

```
template<class TB, TB TCons, class TF, TF TDes>
struct foo{}
```

Which is used like so:

```
using bar = foo<decltype(&tb), &tb, decltype(&tf), &tf>;
```

However, it is very clear the code redundancy of both specifying the types of `&tb` and `&tf` as well as the pointers themselves. Is there a way to construct a template class so that I can do something like this instead?

```
using bar = foo<&tb, &tf>;
```

Comment: Not currently. There are proposals to allow something like `template<auto X>`, but they are just proposals.

Comment: Do you really need pointers values at compile time?

Comment: @gomons No, but it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of C++17, we can now use `auto` as the type of a template parameter, so we can now do this:

```
template<auto TCons, auto TDes>
struct foo{};
```

If we need to get the types of `TCons` and `TDes` we can use `decltype`.

Answer (score 0):

*This is the closest I got. (Not a complete solution.)*

It uses function parameter template auto-deduction, but you still have to specify the parameter-list twice. Another approach was to use auto return type deduction (C++1y) but that has the problem that you can't get the arguments past the parameter-list barrier.

```
template<class TB, class TF> 
struct foo_h {
  template<TB TCons, TF TDes>
  struct f { 
    typedef foo<TB,TCons,TF,TDes> type;
  };  
};

template<class TB, class TF> 
foo_h<TB,TF> foo_t(TB, TF);

using bar = decltype(foo_t(&tb,&tf))::f<&tb,&tf>::type;
```

Maybe it helps somebody to build upon. But I don't think there is a solution, yet.

This is the aforementioned C++1y solution, but as you can see it has the problem of passing the actual variables:

```
template<class TB, class TF>
auto foo_t(TB b, TF f) {
  return foo<TB,&tb,TF,&tf>();
  //            ^^^    ^^^ using b and f doesn't work as they don't refer to globals
}

using tofu = decltype(foo_t(&tb,&tf));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not yet possible.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor is evil, remember it:

```
#define FUNC(f) decltype(f), f

using bar = foo<FUNC(&tb), FUNC(&tf)>;
```